# why the JDBCs connection of service and dao are the same？

Tags: java, jdbc

Just a simple demo of MVC.

1. In the Service class, there is a

   ```
   JDBCutil db=new JDBCutil();
   db.beginTransation();
   UserinfoDao dao=new UserinfoDao();
   ```
2. In the UserinfoDao class, there is also a

   ```
   JDBCutil db=new JDBCutil();
   ```

I thought there are two `new JDBCutil`, but there actually exists only one connection.

Why? Because of the `db.beginTransation();`? and why?

I am sorry that is my fault that not post the JDBCutil(thanks for the mention of comment), it maybe the "static connection"(looks like Singleton) one connection although two new .the code is

```
private static Connection conn=null;
private PreparedStatement pst;
//获取Connection连接
public Connection getConnection(){
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        System.out.println("加载Oracle驱动成功");
        String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.25.39.252:1521:orcl";
        String userName="cccda";
        String pwd="123456";
        if(conn==null){
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, pwd);
        }
        System.out.println("获取Connection连接成功");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("加载Oracle驱动失败");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("获取Connection连接失败");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: What is JDBCUtil? If you wrote it yourself, you may simply have written buggy code. If it is not your own code, you need to at least point us to the library you're using and post a [mcve].

Comment: You are declaring `conn` as a `static` member, which means there is only one. If you don't want that, then don't write that.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a new `JDBCutil` instance, but that's not an actual JDBC `Connection`.  It might wrap a singleton connection with a per-user instance class.  Without the code, we can't tell.

Also, since you see the word `new` twice, the `JDBCutil` instances are not the same, but again that doesn't mean they aren't both using the same JDBC `Connection`.

Odds are the `db.beginTransaction()` calls code internally that maps back to the same connection.  If it didn't I'd imagine that you would have even bigger problems.

Comment: this is the code and thanks for your comment.it looks like Singleton.